# How do you say "mental" in American dialects of English?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation

I usually refer to Cambridge Dictionary for pronunciation. For [*mental*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mental?a=british#dataset-british) they have the IPA of:

> ## mental
>
> *adjective* · UK /ˈmen.tᵊl/ US /-t̬ᵊl/

When I click on the US pronunciation, I hear them saying /ˈmen.dəl/ with a D. You can see *mental* on Cambridge at [this](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mental) link.

But when I check the Longman Pronunciation Dictionary for the US pronunciation, I hear /ˈmen.təl/ same UK? You can see the pronunciation at [this](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/mental) link.

My question is, which one of those is right and which one of those wrong?

Comment: In that context (following a stressed vowel), American pronunciation normally neutralizes /t/ and /d/, pronouncing both as an alveolar flap [ɾ]. An intervening nasal as in _mental_ doesn't affect the flapping (in many cases the nasal would simply appear as a nasalized stressed vowel). This neutralization is the reason for the seeming homophony in American speech of _matter_ and _madder_, for example. As it happens, phonemic contrasts are not universal.

Comment: @JohnLawler The computer-generated voice at Cambridge is fibbing: it really does sound like Mendel there, which nobody says. Longman’s version is correct.

Comment: The pronunciation at Cambridge sounds like something between /t/ and /d/, but it's hard to tell because it's so short and unstressed. I think it's just indicating that our T's are often not as staccato as Brits.

Comment: Listen to all the other on-line dictionaries for American pronunciation. They all aspirate the 't' distinctly, which is articulate American pronunciation. There is a process of softening the 't' in American speech where in fast non-articulate speech it just gets dropped (ie /menl/) but no one says /mendl/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug here is that the computer-generated voice given at [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mental?a=british#dataset-british) **is lying to you**. It’s simply wrong: nobody in America pronounces *mental* to make it sound just Gregor Mendel’s surname.

The pronunciation at [the Longman link](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/mental) by a real speaker is correct. Moreover, those are the same pronunciation for both UK and US. There is no phonemic difference here between countries.

Comment: Is Cambridge really computer generated? I couldn't tell. But I listened to dictionary.com and it was noticeably artificial. I don't think they are entirely discountable, but it does allow a lot of skepticism for the nuances we're asking here.

Comment: Never underestimate the power of human stupidity...  I'm sure there are people, perhaps _especially_ here in America, who mispronounce it that way (heck, there are folks who say "would of"!) but yes, "mendel" is certainly not the usual or accepted pronunciation.   8^)

Comment: @RogerSinasohn Nobody **says** "would of", no not one. They say /ˈwʊdəv/.

Comment: t's not a computer generated voice. If it were, [mantle](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mantle) and mental would have the same consonant (represented in the Cambridge dictionary by [t̬] , which undoubtedly stands for a flapped /t/). They don't.

Comment: It's not computer-generated. The voice actor was probably misled by the transcription.

Comment: 'Bitter' and 'bidder' sound the same to Americans, don't they? It's the same principle here, though many Americans pronounce 'mental' as 'mennel'.

Comment: @AeonAkechi No, because it’s not possible to have a [ɾ] after a nasal, least of all a dental one. The point of contact for the tongue-tap won’t let you do both.

Answer (score 3):

Some dictionaries such as Cambridge use the letter 't̬', the International Phonetic Alphabet character meaning [t] but voiced, i.e. [d], for an instance of /t/ that may undergo [flapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flapping) in North American English. This is not a problem for /t/ that is pronounced consistently the same as /d/ in the same environment, as in *latter* and *ladder*, because /t/ and /d/ here are pronounced identically as a [tap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dental_and_alveolar_flaps) (aka flap; IPA: [ɾ]). Some other dictionaries therefore use 'd', because the difference between /t/ and /d/ is [neutralized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutralization_(linguistics)) in these contexts.†

Flapping of /t/ is almost always present after a stressed syllable, as in *notice*, *protestant*, etc., in North American English, but not necessarily so in other environments. In *positive*, *ability*, *monitor*, etc., /t/ may not be pronounced as [ɾ] as often as in the aforementioned words. But dictionaries which use 't̬' do often use 't̬' for /t/ in these environments too, so for these words 't̬' is better understood as a shorthand for "/t/ that may optionally be pronounced as [ɾ], but not always".

Adding to the confusion, these dictionaries also use 't̬' for /t/ in words like *winter*, which may be pronounced the same as *winner* in North America. But *winter* never rhymes with *hinder*, nor does *center* with *gender*.†† What they should indicate instead, in my opinion, is the fact that /t/ in an intervocalic /nt/ cluster may be omitted, not voiced. Some other dictionaries therefore transcribe, quite rightly in my view, e.g. *winter* as /ˈwɪn(t)ər/. (But note the /nt/-cluster reduction isn't quite as ubiquitous as the flapping of /t/ following stress.)

**TL;DR:** So in dictionaries like Cambridge, the American pronunciation notations for words like *mental*, /ˈmen.t̬ᵊl/, are better understood as "either [ˈmen.tᵊl] or [ˈmen.ᵊl]",††† even though /ˈlæt̬.ɚ/ means always the same as /ˈlæd.ɚ/ (phonetically [ˈlæɾ.ɚ]), and /ˈpɑː.zə.t̬ɪv/ means "either [ˈpɑː.zə.tɪv] or [ˈpɑː.zə.ɾɪv]".

---

† Even the author of a pronunciation dictionary that uses 't̬' [approves of the use of 'd' for flapped /t/](http://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/wells/blog0809b.htm) (see the 23 Sept '08 entry).

†† There are a handful of exceptions: *seventy, ninety,* and *carpenter*, in which /nt/ may be pronounced not just with [nt] or [ɾ] but also with [nd]. I am not aware, however, of such words other than these three.

††† To be precise, the result of the /nt/ reduction is usually a nasalized tap [ɾ̃] (a shorter [n]), but /n/ in the same context (as in *winner*) is also often [ɾ̃], so I found it would be too finicky to make a distinction between [n] and [ɾ̃] here. See the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flapping) for more.

Answer (score 0):

As other users have mentioned, /nt/ may be optionally lenited in American English in the same contexts where /t/ may be lenited to a voiced "flap" or "tap" sound. The usual phonetic transcription I have seen used for the reduced "nt" cluster is a nasalized flap/tap: words like "winter" and "center" may be pronounced as [wiɾ̃ɚ] and [sɛɾ̃ɚ] respectively.

It's not entirely clear to me if this is merged with /n/ for all speakers [edit: I just noticed that the Wikipedia article that Nardog linked to says this varies by dialect], but in any case, the sound [ɾ̃] is perceived as at least very close to [n], so this phenomenon makes the words sound like "winner" and "senner".

I don't feel like this is particularly likely with the word "mental", but I think I have heard "flapping" of the /nt/ in the similarly formed word "environmental".

Using [nt] should always sound OK, so that's the pronunciation that I would recommend for a non-native speaker.